# Package "linux-headers" not available in Kali Linux

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, linux-headers

I found a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_Payl5FlgQ) of how to install Kali Linux on VirtualBox. Everything was going fine, until I enter this command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y linux-headers - $(uname -r)
```

It says that package `linux-headers` is not availabe but is referred by another package and I get these errors:

```
E: Package 'linux-headers' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package 5.7.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '5.7.0-kali1-amd64'
```

---

Also, what does parameter `-y` means in `sudo apt install -y linux-headers - $(uname -r)`?

Answer (score 1):

Don’t add spaces:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

The `-y` arguments answers “yes” to all non-essential prompts. In this particular case, it will avoid `apt` stopping to wait for input after listing the packages it’s going to install.